My AC Cooling Stops After 30 Minutes or so in Skoda Fabia 2008: Compressor or Electrical Problem?
I own a 2008 Skoda Fabia, and recently I've been experiencing an issue with the AC. It cools fine for about 30 minutes, but then the cooling stops, although the fan keeps blowing air. To get it working again, I have to turn the car off and on.
I visited a local AC technician who thought the issue was with the compressor wall, the high-pressure switch, and the water pump (since he noticed the engine was running hot). I replaced all of these parts, but the problem persisted. While replacing the compressor wall, I noticed a black oil-like substance leaking from the compressor. However, the technician assured me that if the compressor or condenser were the problem, the cooling wouldn't work at all, not even for the first 30 minutes. We also tried removing and reinserting the same evap sensor below the steering wheel and noticed that the pipes were getting frozen when removed and the ice melted when inserted.
I then took the car to a different technician, who tested the power supply to the compressor by attaching a light bulb to the compressor wire. After about 30 minutes, the light went out, indicating the power was being cut off. When the car was restarted, the light and the AC came back on. He was certain that the issue was electrical, not with the compressor or the AC system itself, since the cooling would restart once the power was restored.
We scanned the car, and the only error that came up was related to the drive battery voltage ("implausible signal"), which the technician said wasn’t related to the AC issue. He ran tests on various car modules, and while checking, the wipers activated randomly, and the AC started cooling again, only to stop after 30 minutes as usual. Despite the tests, no significant errors appeared, except for the battery voltage issue.
The technician now believes the problem lies with the Body Control Module (BCM) and suggests it needs replacing. I'm unsure if this is the real issue, especially since I initially thought the black oil in the compressor indicated a fault with the compressor or condenser. Could it be the BCM, or is there another potential cause? I’d appreciate any advice. Please help. Thanks

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure how the BCM would be involved. It usually does things like keeps the lights/radio (convenience items) on after you shut the car off or tells the inside lights to turn on when you open the door. I didn't think it is involved with the function of the AC. Does your car have auto temperature control (not turn knobs, but a degree setting)? I believe this to be an electronic issue, too, but not seeing how the BCM would have anything to do with it.

You are right, I dont trust the advice of replacing the bcm as well. My car has knobs for temperature control. no auto control.

Are these techs trained on vehicle ac systems? What do you mean by "compressor wall"? A 2008 is now 16yrs old, old enough for normal wear and tear with one fact universal to vehicle ac systems; the leak no one wants to address. Virtually all ac systems have protection sensors to disable compressor operation when refrigerant leaks out. Your system may be low on refrigerant. Refrigeration gauges and a person familiar with operating pressures can determine if your system leaked and lost refrigerant that may be contributing to intermittent operation. In addition, the cooling fan must run when ac runs; it forces airflow thru the hot ac condenser coil in front of a hot radiator. A dead or failing cooling fan(s) can diminish ac operation from higher operating pressures by sensors automatically disabling compressor operation.

How would the fact cycling ignition (shutting car off) restores the AC for another 30-ish minutes come into play here? If the OP can shut the car off, turn it back on right away, and the AC will work fine, it seems to me it's not something to do with it mechanically, but electronicially. Something is getting reset during the power cycle which is allowing the system to work.

A combination low/high pressure sensor detecting just enough loss of refrigerant can trigger a disable signal to the ecm to cut power to the compressor. In the time compressor power is off, system pressure immediately begins to equalize, any high pressure bleeds off into the low side, raising pressure above the set point of the pressure sensor to allow compressor operation. Pressure equalization begins as soon as the compressor is turned off. This can repeat when operating pressures are not normal. This is only one possible issue since the OP has not posted actual low and high side pressures.

Wouldn't normal AC cycling do the same thing? You wouldn't need to shut the vehicle off for it to come back to a point where the ECM would call things good and then start anew.

I'm describing loss of refrigerant occurring, leaks, although it may appear as a cycling compressor when its not. A leak eventually causes lower low and high side pressures.  For r134a systems, pressures below 30 psi (low side) can lead to freezing evaporator coils. Thermal expansion valves are regulated to operate down to 35 psi to prevent freezing coils from occurring. The combination low/high pressure sensor, mounted on the high side protects against excessive loss of refrigerant (below approximately 40 psi. Loss of refrigerant also means less lubricating oil returning to the compressor.

Refrigerant moves oil throughout a system. Less or zero refrigerant means no oil returning to lube the compressor, resulting in self destruction without the low/high pressure sensor. I'm not privy to every vehicle ac system and some older r12 systems did cycle compressors. Designing variable displacement and solenoid controlled compressors eliminates engine load when compressors are cycling; varying displacement in proportion to cooling needs while reducing engine surge and hesitation characteristic of older cycling compressors.

First of all thank you all so much for these advice and thoughts. By compressor wall - I mean a compressor valve that is like a cylindrical stick that comes inside the compressor that modulates between pressure. If there is a leak as suggested by @FDryer, why isn't the entire refrigerant leaking out? It starts cooling after shutting it off and on. Please guide. Thanks

I actually don't know the high and low-pressure values, if you need it, I can attach a picture by tomorrow. Your help would be appreciated. Also, yes it seems to be as an electronic issue as well but you guys know better. something that I just started to think is if the ac cooling starts immediately after it goes off after I switch it off and on or do I have to give it time. The reason of this thought is - if the ac is switched back on immediately after it goes after igniting off and on - it can hint at an electrical issue if it takes time to get the cooling back, it can be mechanical right?

Yes, if you can, report high and low side pressures with engine idling around 1200 rpm, not idle. Also, post a snapshot of the engine area and close up of the compressor. Your description of a cylinder inside compressor may be pistons (several). There are compressors using vanes and Subaru using a digitally controlled electric solenoid to vary compressor output. If interested, examine labeling on the compressor and post it.

Yes, i will send you pictures of all this. You are right I meant electric solenoid. That was replaced.

I am unable to add pictures of the low and high pressure reading here in the comment. So added it here - https://ibb.co/sQsHpG5
https://ibb.co/JHCYM2Y
https://ibb.co/RpmQbtX - The high-pressure switch and the valve was solenoid was replaced. The latest update is that the condenser, expansion valve and compressor was changed too since the system was contaminated. The entire system was flushed - still the ac seems to stop cooling after 45 minutes.

30+psi/low side seems a little lower than ideal, 200+psi/hi side appears higher than normal. Does the cooling fan run or not? The cooling fan always runs when ac is running. A dead or slow running (worn out) cooling fan will allow discharge/high side pressures to increase to dangerous levels when the combination low/high pressure sensor detects out of range values and sends a disable signal to the ecm. The ecm disables compressor power until pressures subside; system pressures equalize - high pressures lower, low pressures rise until the high side pressures drop to safe operating pressure when the pressure sensor detects it and sends a signal to the ecm to enable power to the compressor.
Open the engine hood with engine idling, ac off. On a warm day, the cooling fan may run or not, depending on engine coolant temperatures. Pressurized cooling systems run as hot as 220F/104C when the cooling fan turns on and turns off when coolant temps drop below approximately 210F/99C.When ac is turned on, the cooling fan turns on immediately to force airflow thru ac condenser coil and hot radiator to prevent ac pressures from rising above a certain pressure, and coolant from overheating. If the cooling fan runs at low speed when ac is turned on, it may be worn out. On very hot days, the two speed cooling fan should alternate between low and high speed with ac running. On hot days with ac on, in stop and go traffic, the fan should be running at high speed.


Yes the cooling fan does run visually. it runs at good enough speed. However I am unsure if the fan runs irrespective of the ac being switched on or not. But I can definitely hear the fan having two speed. One that makes a bit more running volume and it switches off to a quieter mode too. I am a noob at these things.
